# What is the proper way to set cursor css in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
$('#spanContainingImage').hover(function () {
            //$(this).css('cursor',"vertical-text");//this works
            console.log('hover');//this is called
            $(this).css('cursor', "url('http://localhost:12062/Content/themes/base/images/G.cur')");//this fails
        });
```

I tried hard coding my URL, I still cannot get the cursor to change by URL.  What's wrong?

Comment: What happens when you visit http://localhost:12062/Content/themes/base/images/G.cur in a browser? Does IIS / IISExpress / Cassini have a mime type for the .cur extension?

Comment: @olivehour - I see a blank page.  I tried accessing the directory with a bad image name `/badimage.no` and got an error.

Comment: If there is no file named badimage.no in the folder, you would get a HTTP 404 error. However, the first thing I would check is whether or not the server is not showing the image because it doesn't understand the mime-type for the .cur extension.

Comment: I tried adding MIME type to IIS5.  I tried .cur MIME=image/x-icon and then MIME=image/vnd.microsoft.icon.  No go.  I cannot see the image with a direct visit on the URL.  The image does not show for cursor on hover.  Tried IE7 and FF7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) says:

> [...] zero or more URLs may be specified (comma-separated), which **must**
>   be followed by  one of the keywords defined in the CSS specification,
>   such as auto or pointer.

So I added the `auto` modifier to my jQuery

```
var url = 'url(@Url.Content("Content/themes/base/images/G.png")), auto';            
$(this).css('cursor', url);
```

Now it works.

Note that it is also stated you have to stick to .CUR and .ANI to maintain IE6 compatibility (wish it listed IE7).

Comment: you should still use the relative path to the file instead of hard coded one

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#spanContainingImage').hover(function () {
            //$(this).css('cursor',"vertical-text");//this works
            console.log('hover');//this is called
            $(this).css('cursor', "url(" + '@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/G.cur")' + ")");//this fails
        });
```

Comment: Still no go.  I do not see any errors in firebugs console window in either case.

Comment: Did You try doing this in console: `$('#spanContainingImage').css('cursor', 'url("pathhere")');` Also put the file on a live server and use a path to that

Answer (score 0):

Just looked up a working example on W3schools. Have you tried without quoting your URL? i.e.

url(http://localhost:12062/Content/themes/base/images/G.png)

instead of

url('http://localhost:12062/Content/themes/base/images/G.png')

Comment: A direct visit to the URL shows the image.  The cursor does not change.  AFAIK you need to use a *.cur file to change a cursor image.

Comment: I'm confused: Does a direct visit to the URL show the image or not? You said in one comment that it does, and in another comment that it does not.

Comment: Direct visit to the .cur version of the image does *not* show.  Direct visit to the .png version of the image does show.

Comment: +1 - while this wasnt the answer, several of your comments helped narrow things down.